# How Can I use Same Adapter of a GridView on Different activities

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview

Let say I have two Activities, Activity A and Activity B.

Activity A displays a list of images using the Adapter Z.

When user clicks on any image in Activity A, they will be taken to Activity B to show the full image. I'm passing image path and grid position to Activity using Intent.

Now in Activity B, I place a delete button which should delete the imagepath from the gridview adapter.

Problem is: 
How can I access the Activity A adapter in activity B to call remove(position) method in my adapter.

So I can call notifyDataSetChanged in onResume of Activity A to update the gridview images.

**Activity A**

```
MyGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
MyGridView .setAdapter(adapter );    

Intent fullImageActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
    fullImageActivity.putExtra("position", position);
    fullImageActivity.putExtra("path", mediaPath);
    startActivity(fullImageActivity);
```

**Activity B**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
// I'm getting position and path from setOnItemClickListener
position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");
path = i.getExtras().getString("path");

// I want to remove path from my adapter after clicking delete button in Activity B
```

**Adapter**

```
public ArrayList<String> images;

    public void remove(int position){
            images.remove(position);
        }
```

Comment: save your position in Activity B using static variable or shared pref. and In Activity A remove position from arraylist and notify it

Comment: Yeah, I know doing it. But I want to remove the position from Activity B itself.

Comment: you have gridview in Activity B?

Comment: No, Activity B has only one ImageView to show the image clicked on Activity A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [startActivityForResult](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example).

```
Intent fullImageActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
    fullImageActivity.putExtra("position", position);
    fullImageActivity.putExtra("path", mediaPath);

   startActivityForResult(fullImageActivity, 2);
```

check if deleted at particular position in `Activity B` . here I override `onBackPressed()` (For Ex.) method

```
public void onBackPressed(){

   super.onBackPressed()

Intent intent=new Intent();  
                    intent.putExtra("isdeleted",true);  
intent.putExtra("pos",position);
                    setResult(2,intent);  
                    finish();
}
```

Handle it in `onActivityResult` in `Activity A`.

```
 @Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                            if(data.getBooleanExtra("isdeleted")){   
                           remove from position array and notify dataset change. // pos = data.getIntExtra("pos") 
                            }
                         }  
     }
```

Sorry for TYPO.

Comment: I already tried it. But the problem is, User can swipe the images left/right to see more images in Activity B. So, they can delete multiple images before coming back to Activity A. This is the reason i'm trying to remove the position in Activity B itself.

Comment: so pass arraylist or pass position separated by comma and on activityresult create array from string split by comma.

Comment: will it work even if user clicks the back button in Action Bar?

Comment: for that you have to call in your icon click event. basically it is home click

Comment: don't know why, onActivityResult is not triggered when back press. It is calling onResume

Comment: have you put @Override on it.

Comment: Yep working fine. Trying to handle multiple delete's now. Thanks for nice solution. I still wonder is it not possible to call the adapter from activity B? it will make work very easier.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that you need to share the data and not really the adapter.

### Using a singleton

You can use a singleton class to hold the image data and then access the same in both the activities. This ensures sync between both activities at all times.

#### Singleton Class

```
public class ImageData{
   private ArrayList<ImageModel> mDataOfImages;
   private ImageData mHelperInstance;

   private ImageData(){
         //private constructor to ensure singleton
   }

   public static ImageData getInstance(){
      // return an ImageData instance according to your implementation
      // of singleton pattern
   }

   private void setData(ArrayList<ImageModel> newData){
       this.mDataOfImages = newData;
   }

   private void removeImage(int position){
       if(this.mDataOfImages !=null && this.mDataOfImages.size() > position){
         mDataOfImages.remove(position);
     }
   }
```

}

#### Activity A

```
private void saveImageData(ArrayList<ImageModel> data){
     if(data !=null){
          if(mAdapter !=null){
              mAdapter.setData(data);
          }
     }
}

//Call notifydatasetchanged when activity is opened again
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    if(mAdapter !=null){
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

#### MyAdapter

```
public void setData(ArrayList<ImageMode> newData){
     if(newData !=null){
        ImageDataSingleton.getInstance().setData(newData);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
}
```

#### Activity B

Use the singleton class to display images in Activity B. Because you are using the model array list, you can easily implement right/left swipes and delete multiple images.

```
//Delete a image
private void deleteImage(){
     ImageDataSingleton.getInstance().removeImage(getCurrentPosition());
 // Rest of deletion handling like moving to right or left image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should build your remove method in activity A and be sure that it is static:

```
public static void remove(int position){
        images.remove(position);
    }
```

now you can call it from activity B like this:

```
ActivityA.remove(position);
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Not working, "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context”

Comment: But at above, I recommended that you make your method static: ' public static void remove(int position) '  Please send your complete code. Maybe I can help you.